# List styling in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view

I have a list in SharePoint that is housing all the company news, I want to now customise the way this looks and despite trying to do so with a custom list view I'm not getting anywhere.  How can I customise my list view and by customise I mean add code like `<div>` etc?

Comment: Code like etc ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to be able to customise the list view extensively.  I want to bring it inline with my branding and I can't do that at the moment, I can't add code to the custom list view I have made via SharePoint Designer.  I want to be able to change the way the table is put together etc so quick in depth.  I found this which touches on what I'm talking about http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-view-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010379079.aspx

Comment: If it's that customized why don't you go for a Visual Web Part instead ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2013, we have access to the JSLink property, which allows you to specify a js file that contains custom rendering code for a list web part. Just search for "sharepoint 2013 jslink" to find lots of resources, or check out the following:

http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

Answer (score 1):

You could add a content editor web part with CSS to the page with the list.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want your custom rendering in the list view without adding custom server side code,  that is pretty much possible with two scenarios:-

1. Create a jQuery script that reads list item using web services and create your custom rendering.
2. You can think of using  [XSLT List View Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff606773%28v=office.14%29.aspx) this is most preffered way,  just develop yoru XSLT that wraps around your field onto custom  elements.  and update your list view web part property (XSL Link) to point to your xslt file.

This is really very simple and should help you.

Refer:
[XSLT and SharePoint](http://paylord.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/xslt-and-sharepoint-part-1/)

Comment: As XSLT is a server side technology, it is no longer recommended for SharePoint 2013, as MS is encouraging client-side development.

Comment: Mike,  seriously...I doubt that,  XSLT is not a server side thing,  you just develop XSLT file and upload it to your Style Library,  I have recently used it in my SharePoint 2013 environment and it works great.

Comment: I'm sure it works great for you, but the XSLT is executed by the server and only HTML content is returned to the client. So, yes, it works, but server-side functionality is not the direction MS is pushing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on this, I was liking the look of XSLT but could gain a lot more from the benefits of using jslink.  Does anyone have any good examples of its use? Everything I look at is for doing advanced things like adding status bars when all I'm looking to do is some styling.

Comment: Have you checked out Zimmergren's samples? They're usually pretty good: http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013